# Understanding and visualizing recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I referred to several questions here about recursion but I am not able to understand how recursion works for this particular problem:
Recursive program to get all combination of characters in a string in Python:

```
st= []
def combi(prefix, s):
    if len(s)==0: return 
    else:
        st.append(prefix+s[0])        

        ''' printing values so that I can see what happens at each stage '''
        print "s[0]=",s[0]
        print "s[1:]=",s[1:]
        print "prefix=",prefix
        print "prefix+s[0]=",prefix+s[0]
        print "st=",st

        combi(prefix+s[0],s[1:])
        combi(prefix,s[1:])
        return st

print combi("",'abc')
```

I've made it print the values so that I can see what's happening. This is the output:

```
s[0]= a
s[1:]= bc
prefix= 
prefix+s[0]= a
st= ['a']
s[0]= b
s[1:]= c
prefix= a
prefix+s[0]= ab
st= ['a', 'ab']
s[0]= c
s[1:]= 
prefix= ab
prefix+s[0]= abc
st= ['a', 'ab', 'abc']
s[0]= c
s[1:]= 
prefix= a  ----> How did prefix become 'a' here. Shouldn't it be 'abc' ? 
prefix+s[0]= ac
st= ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac']
.........
.........
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'b', 'bc', 'c'] # final output
```

Full output: http://pastebin.com/Lg3pLGtP

As I've shown in the output, how did prefix become 'ab'?

I tried to visualize the recursive calls for the combi(prefix+s[0],s[1:]). Am I understanding it right? 
[image: Visualization of Recursion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two recursive calls to `combi()` in the function. Thus the path of calls is not a single line, but rather a binary tree that forks. What you are seeing is the second half of the tree.

Comment: I thought the 2nd recursive call i.e `combi(prefix,s[1:])` would start off as `combi('','bc')` and go though the same process forming b,bc.
Here at the last step s[0] is 'c' and when recursing out prefix+s[0] becomes ''+c = c if I understand it right? Btw, I've added a pastbin link of the complete output to the question.

Comment: If you're familiar with depth-first search, it's how the tree Amber mentions is being traversed (or generated, depending on how you want to look at it).

Comment: @RBK: It's the call for `combi('a', 'c')` *from* `combi('a','bc')` that's creating the second `prefix='a'`.

Comment: @ktodisco , Yes I know Depth first traversal. I think the connection with recursion in general would be that DFS uses a stack.. I will try to visualize it on paper & see... I am still not able to understand how the backtracking works exactly.

Comment: @Amber, `prefix+s[0]` is passed as the 1st argument to combi, doesn't prefix now become 'ab' after the call to `combi('a','bc')` ? How does it remain 'a' ?

Comment: `combi('a','bc')` calls `combi('a','c')` for the 2nd of the two recursive calls - `combi(prefix,s[1:])`. Notice how `prefix` is passed unmodified.

Comment: @Amber, thanks! now I get it. I drew the whole tree on paper now including the branch of the 2nd recursive call and I can see how 'ac' was got.

Answer (score 7):

From [this](https://www.recursionvisualizer.com/) excellent browser based python recursion visualizer:

Paste your code as:

```py
st= []
def combi(prefix, s):
    if len(s)==0: 
        return 
    else:
        st.append(prefix+s[0])     
        combi(prefix+s[0],s[1:])
        combi(prefix,s[1:])
        return st
```

And it generates this diagram which you can step through one call at a time. (The truly wonderful thing is the python is executed in your browser using web assembly!)

[image]

You could also look at a stand alone [python module](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz/blob/master/README.md) for that

[image: rcviz output]

Generated with:

```
from rcviz import callgraph, viz
st= []
@viz
def combi(prefix, s):
    if len(s)==0: 
        return 
    else:
        st.append(prefix+s[0])     
        combi.track(st = st) #track st in rcviz 
        combi(prefix+s[0],s[1:])
        combi(prefix,s[1:])
        return st

print combi("",'abc')
callgraph.render("combi.png")
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I drew the recursion tree. By Depth First Traversal, the final output is got at the last node.
This visualization helps understand what's happening.

[image: Recursion Tree]

Answer (score 1):

I've written a python package called [recursion-visualiser](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer) which helps to draw a recursion tree for any arbitary recursive function. You have to simply add a decorator and boom you have nice animation and recursion tree saved as gif and png.

```
from visualiser.visualiser import Visualiser as vs

st= []
@vs(show_argument_name=False, node_properties_kwargs={"shape":"record", 
"color":"#f57542", "style":"filled", "fillcolor":"grey"})
def combi(prefix, s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return " "
    else:
        st.append(prefix + s[0])
        combi(prefix=prefix + s[0], s=s[1:])
        combi(prefix=prefix, s=s[1:])
        return st

print(combi(prefix="",s='abc'))
vs.make_animation("combinations.gif", delay=3)
```

Here is the  output gif:
[image: combinations.gif] 
Also, a recursion tree saved as png with return value:
[image: combinations.png]

Check out more examples [here](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer/tree/master/examples).